# pg_dump through ssh stops after some seconds when use in script

Tags: postgresql, shell, pg-dump

I do backup of three PostgreSQL servers with pgdump launched by script through ssh. The command line in script is :

```
sudo -u barman ssh postgres@$SERVER 'pg_dump -Fc -b $database 2> ~/dump_error.txt' | gzip > $DUMP_ROOT/$SERVER-$BACKUPDATE.gz
```

But the dump size is always about 1K, for all servers. When I execute this line in a shell, just replacing the variable by their values, that perfectly works. It executed it as root (sudo -u barman ssh postgres@server ...), and as barman, just as user barman (ssh postgres@server ...), the dump is correct.

When I open the dump, I see the start of dump, but suddenly it stops.

The dump_error.txt on servers is empty.

There is nothing in log (postgres log and syslog), in backup and PostgreSQL servers.

The user barman can connect to server as user postgres without password.

The limits of shell are enough high to not block the script (open files 1024, file size unlimited, max user process 13098).

I try to change the cron hour of script, thinking that a process could consume all resources, but it is always the same thing, and ps -e show nothing special.

The version of postgreSQL is 9.1.

Why does this line never produce a complete dump when executed in script, but only when executed in a shell ?

Thanks for your help, Denis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is related to bad quoting. Simple quotes will cause the string to not be expanded, while double quotes will expand what's inside. For instance :

```
>MYVARIABLE=test
>echo '$MYVARIABLE'
$MYVARIABLE
>echo "$MYVARIABLE"
test
```

In your case, `ssh postgres@$SERVER 'pg_dump -Fc -b $database 2> ~/dump_error.txt'` will execute the command on the remote computer, without expanding variables. This means ssh will pass the expression `pg_dump -Fc -b $database`, and bash will interprete the variable `$database` on the remote computer. If this variable doesn't exist there, it will be considered an empty string.

You can see the difference when you do `ssh user@server 'echo $PWD'` and `ssh user@server "echo $PWD"`.